# Word frequency from a specific CSV column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I need to read how many times a number comes up in a specific column. Here's the code I'm trying to get working, but it does not work.

```
words= []
with open('random.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
         csv_words = row[12].split(" ")
         for i in csv_words:
              words.append(i)
words_counted = []

print (words_counted)
for i in words:
    x = words.count(i)
    words_counted.append((i,x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after running your code it seemed to work with one caveat. It counted words twice.
Ex: with the cell having "word1 word1 word2 word3":
[('word1', 2), ('word1', 2), ('word2', 1), ('word3', 1)]

This can be solved by instead of using a list for words counted, using a dict.

```
words_counted = dict()
```

For each word, if it's not already in the dict, initialize it to 1:

```
wordDict[word] = 1
```

If it is already in the dict, increment it:

```
wordDict[word] += 1
```

Is this the issue you're having, or is there something else?
If it's something else, would you mind providing a sample of the csv?

Edit:

```
import csv
existingFish= dict()
with open('fishData.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        fishName = row[12]
        if fishName in existingFish:
            existingFish[fishName] += 1
        else:
            existingFish[fishName] = 1
```

Comment: The csv file contains a lot of random information, which later is being used with matplotlib. Here's the first line of the file:

`A A 0001;969159570;ENVIRONMENTAL AND LIFE SCIENCE;MAILBOX 5003;1432;�S;03-10-1991;;3021;�S;Commercial;FISH;SALMON;0,00;TN;10362;RIVER;3021;�S;FRESHWATER;6,50;TN;59.668083;10.758450`

So, I need to count how many times a certain fish comes up in the csv file. Using encoding='iso-8859-1'

Comment: Ok. I think i understand better. Added some code to the answer. Does the above do what you want?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it works. Would it be possible for the output to be printed downwards, and not sideways, and for the code to skip the first line the csv file, hence there's a header there?

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/),

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('random.csv', header=False) # USE header=False IF CSV HAS NO HEADER
```

Select 13th column (Index starts from 0) and check frequency,

```
df.iloc[:, 12].value_counts()
```

OR

```
df['column_name'].value_counts()
```

---

OR

In your code, use `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(words))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how to implement it into my code. Do you mean that I replace my code with your panda solution?

Comment: I'm not getting it to output anything. I had to modify it a bit to match my csv file.

`df = pd.read_csv("random.csv", delimiter=";", skiprows=1, encoding="iso-8859-1")`

Comment: Add some rows from file to the post.